# Where to get OpenLayers plugin compatible with QGIS 2.14?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-openlayers-plugin, plugins

I'm trying to download **OpenLayers Plugin - 1.1.0**  from

http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml but I'm getting something like this in settings

[image: This plugin is incompatible... error]

Where can I get an OpenLayers plugin compatible with QGIS 2.14?

Comment: Why do you want an old version of the plugin? Current is 1.4.1: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/openlayers_plugin/

Answer (score 5):

The standard way to install any plugin compatible with the version of QGIS you are using is to use the `Manage and Install Plugins` option from the QGIS Plugin menu.

[image: Manage and Install Plugins]

Search for the Plugin you want and install:

[image: Installing the OpenLayers Plugin for QGIS 2.14]

For me I can get a compatible version of the OpenLayers plugin for QGIS 2.14 in this way.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access the official plugin repository for a specific QGIS version, you need to include `?qgis=2.14`. So your link should instead be:

http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml?qgis=2.14

From here, we can see that the OpenLayers plugin v1.4.1 (as mentioned by [@AndreJ)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/9159/andrej) and various other plugins are compatible with QGIS 2.14.